# Vi on freeBSD : stuck into "ex input mode"

Tags: vim, vi, freebsd

I'm stuck in a file. I used vi to edit this file, and I tried to quit, but I got a message like "Entering ex input mode". It doesn't work if I press `Escape`, it writes `^[` in my file.

How can I properly close my file now?

Comment: You mean just typing ZZ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In ex input mode you type line by line and see these lines at the bottom of the screen. 
When you done simply type a new line consist of single period (.).
This will take you out of the ex input mode.

Hope this help!

Answer (score 34):

The `:visual` command gets you out of it.

If your `vi` is actually `Vim`, you can find that information via `:help Ex-mode`, listed under the `Q` command, which gets you into that mode.

Comment: Well, `:w` should save your changes, `:q` should quit vi. If at least the first succeeds, you can `kill` the `vi` process as a last resort.

Comment: In another terminal, type `ps | grep vi`. Then use the first column's number `N` in `kill N`. If this is the only vi open, `killall vi` is a shorter alternative.

Comment: I finally found how to exit... I just hit Ctrl-C ^^ Thank you anyway. I found a way to disable that mode.

Comment: BTW, my PC-BSD vi (version 1.79 (10/23/96)) supports `:vi` and `:q`.

Comment: Please comment how, so that others in the same situation have a solution!

Comment: Typing any command in ex input mode doesn't do anything because they do get interpreted as commands. All that it gets treated as is a string of text input that you can't even backspace.

Answer (score 0):

I FOUND IT. I just spammed everything while pressing the control key. press "control z" and it will suspend vi

Comment: Suspending is not the same thing as quitting.